# Why do I need to constantly renew my Google Auth Access Token?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

In Php, I'm using the Gmail API to read and remove mails from a generic email address.
It's running perfectly but I always need (several times per day) to regenerate a new access token to give access to my script to the mail box, why ?

I have specified an Approval Prompt on "force" which is supposed to work forever.
Last point, I'm using the Google client library with composer (google/apiclient version 2.0)

Here is my Php code:

```
private function getClient()
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('My app');
    $client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
    $configPath = CONFIG . 'client_secret_123456790.apps.googleusercontent.com.json';
    $client->setAuthConfig($configPath);
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->setLoginHint('email@example.com');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('consent');

    $tokenPath = CONFIG . 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. It may not be anything specific to your code. Have you had your app *verified* by Google? In regards to the Oauth Consent Screen in the developer's console.

Comment: @getset No I did not but I'm going to do it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @herve you dont have a choice about verification really.  If you are going to have more then 100 users attached to this or go over the limit of requests you will need to go though the verification process because gmail is a sensitive scope.

Comment: @DaImTo It's a Php script that is accessing one, and only one Gmail account, 1 time per hour from 8:00AP to 18:00PM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's running perfectly but I always need (several times per day) to regenerate a new access token to give access to my script to the mail box, why ?

Access tokens are only valid for one hour this is standard for Oauth.  You are requesting off line access so there for have a refresh token which can be used to request a new access token from the authencation server.

> I have specified an Approval Prompt on "force" which is supposed to work forever.

If you include `approval Prompt on "force"` in your request then it will force the user to login again and grant your application consent to the scopes.  I have no idea where you got the idea that this cause it to work for ever.

## Oauth2

You are using oauth2 access tokens expire after one hour using offline access will give you a refresh token which you can store and use to request a new access token when ever your access token expires

You appear to have implemented this already If its not working i sugest you check that the code is being hit and that you have not lost the refresh token somehow.

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

## storing the refresh token

I cant find anywhere in your code that you are saving the refresh token When you authenticate the user the first time.  You will get a refresh token back you should store this in a file somewhere then you can use it to create a new access token the next time you run your script

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken("TokenFromFile");
```

The refresh token is only returned the first time the user authenticates your application or when you add approval prompt force.  There should be no reason to over write this token unless you haven't used it for more than six months.

Comment: my script is accessing the Gmail account only 1 time per hour, If I change this access to, let say, every 30 minutes, will it change someting? Concerning the "force" option on approval Prompt, it's coming from several comments on Github (in the project's homepage)

Comment: Your still going to need to request a new access token using your refresh token.  It wont change anything that you are doing it every thirty minutes or not.  Just try to figure out whats wrong with your refresh token i suspect its being over written or forgotten somehow.   You only need to save it once when you first authenticate your user after that it will be null.

Comment: What github page?  I am a contributor on that library and if something is documented incorrectly i would like to fix it.   Approval prompt force will force the user to login again and approve consent and return you a new refresh token which you dont need if you properly save the one you have in a separate file some where.

Comment: see this page https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/263 (search for `force`)

Comment: "you don't need force every time, only when you don't have a refresh token stored on the server."   Yeah thats exactly what i have been trying to tell you.   Theres nothing there that says prompt force would make you never have to refresh an access token.

Comment: As I use to say, the bug is on the chair ! I was saving the token to a file and was using another one... Sorry for my mistake and thank you very much for your help.